# OCR for getting text from images

Tags: python, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, ocr

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSsKO.jpg)

I need to get the text from a few images where there is a meter and I need to read the text from lcd of the meter. i have tried several ways but to no success.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried and what errors/issues you are getting. You're not going to get an answer with this - it's too non-specific. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Use Google Cloud Platform(GCP). You have a lot of APIs for computer vision.
In the OCP they also provide API to Detect text in Image.

Check the link below for a detailed description of how it works.

[GCP OCR Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr)

If this is not what you are looking for then ask your question more descriptive about what exactly the platform you are working and what are all the things you tried so far.

Comment: Already tried microsoft computer vision api, however could not get anything. Only the model no. of the meter could be found. i think the LCD part has different layers and this needs to be decoded first.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what @AntoPravin has answered. Also for the answer to your comment, I'd like to inform you that GCP detection is way more powerful than Microsoft vision API. I've personally compared  [Google's vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr), [Microsoft vision API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/), and [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc), and GCP is miles ahead of both these two. GCP is able to detect almost everything that you can see with your naked eye.

I tried GCP on your image. These are the results and as you can see, I'm able to get the reading of the meter. Getting the numerical value from this text is not a problem. You can use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html) for that.

```
LOBAT
15.4
mv
SHUNT
ATXP 010
ON
 LOBAT 15.4 mv SHUNT ATXP 010 ON
```

---